# Get checked checkboxes generated by foreach loop mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, checkbox, foreach

I am having problems with getting my checked checkboxes into my mvc controller and save them in the database. I generated my list with a for each loop in the create view.

My advert class:

```
    public class Advert
  {
    public int AdvertId { get; set; }
    public int SponsorId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Amount")]
    public int Amount { get; set; }


    [DisplayName("Start date")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yy}")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("End date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yy}")]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public List<Continent> Continents { get; set; }
    public List<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    public List<Sport> Sports { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public Sponsor Sponsor { get; set; }
    public int SponsorTypeId { get; set; }
  }
```

(part of)Create view

```
    <div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SponsorId, "Select sport")
</div>

<div class="editor-field">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Sports)
    {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="@item.SportId" name="SelectedSport" value="@item.SportId"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.SportName
                </td>
            </tr> <br />  
    }   
</div>
```

AdvertController

```
// POST: /Advert/Create
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Advert advert)
{
  ViewBag.SponsorId = new SelectList(db.Sponsors, "SponsorId", "SponsorCompany", advert.SponsorId);
  advert.SponsorTypeId = service.sponsorType(advert.Amount);   

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      db.Adverts.Add(advert);
      db.SaveChanges();
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(advert);
}
```

I am realy stuck at this point for a while so any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you expect the model binder to bind the `SelectedSport` form values when there is no such field in your model? You need to add this into your `Advert` class:

```
public IEnumerable<String> SelectedSport { get; set; }
```

This should then be populated with the values of the selected checkboxes.

Additionally, it seems that you are using your **database** entities **directly in your view**. This is bad! You should create a separate `AdvertViewModel` class and populate this with the values you need in your controller.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just looking to grab the ids then the most straightfoward way is to use a named parameter.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myParams" name="myParams" value="@item.SportId"/>
```

Then just change your definition to pull up that list by name

```
public ActionResult Create(Advert advert, string[] myParams)
```